# Django Fixtures Deserialization Error: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, django, django-fixtures

I am trying to call `python manage.py loaddata fixture_20170717.json` but I get the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Anon\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in
>   raw_decode   raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
>   django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing
>   fixture
>   'D:\resi_django\viewer_django\topology_viewer\viewer\fixtures\fixture_20170717.json':
>   No JSON object could be decoded

The "fixture_20170717.json" file looks like this:

> [ { "model": "viewer.net", "pk": 1, "fields": { "net_name":
>   "Aarnet-tz", "data": { "graph_data": { "nodes": ["Perth1", "Sydney2",
>   "Sydney1", "Armidale", "Brisbane1", "Brisbane2", "Darwin",
>   "Adelaide1", "Adelaide2", "Rockhampton", "Alice,Springs", "Cairns",
>   "Melbourne1", "Canberra2", "Canberra1", "Melbourne2", "Hobart",
>   "Perth2", "Townsville"], "links": [["Perth1", "Adelaide1"], ["Perth1",
>   "Perth2"], ["Sydney2", "Brisbane2"], ["Sydney2", "Armidale"],
>   ["Sydney2", "Sydney1"], ["Sydney2", "Melbourne2"], ["Sydney1",
>   "Brisbane1"], ["Sydney1", "Canberra2"], ["Brisbane1", "Brisbane2"],
>   ["Brisbane1", "Rockhampton"], ["Darwin", "Adelaide1"], ["Darwin",
>   "Alice,Springs"], ["Adelaide1", "Melbourne1"], ["Adelaide1",
>   "Adelaide2"], ["Adelaide2", "Melbourne2"], ["Adelaide2",
>   "Alice,Springs"], ["Adelaide2", "Perth2"], ["Rockhampton",
>   "Townsville"], ["Cairns", "Townsville"], ["Melbourne1", "Hobart"],
>   ["Melbourne1", "Canberra1"], ["Melbourne1", "Melbourne2"],
>   ["Canberra2", "Canberra1"], ["Melbourne2", "Hobart"]] }, "city_data":
>   { "Perth1": { "lat": -31.93333, "long": 115.83333 }, "Sydney2": {
>   "lat": -33.86785, "long": 151.20732 }, "Sydney1": { "lat": -33.86785,
>   "long": 151.20732 }, "Armidale": { "lat": -30.51667, "long": 151.65 },
>   "Brisbane1": { "lat": -27.46794, "long": 153.02809 }, "Brisbane2": {
>   "lat": -27.46794, "long": 153.02809 }, "Darwin": { "lat": -12.46113,
>   "long": 130.84185 }, "Adelaide1": { "lat": -34.93333, "long": 138.6 },
>   "Adelaide2": { "lat": -34.93333, "long": 138.6 }, "Rockhampton": {
>   "lat": -23.38333, "long": 150.5 }, "Alice,Springs": { "lat": -23.7,
>   "long": 133.88333 }, "Cairns": { "lat": -16.91667, "long": 145.76667
>   }, "Melbourne1": { "lat": -37.814, "long": 144.96332 }, "Canberra2": {
>   "lat": -35.28346, "long": 149.12807 }, "Canberra1": { "lat":
>   -35.28346, "long": 149.12807 }, "Melbourne2": { "lat": -37.814, "long": 144.96332 }, "Hobart": { "lat": -42.87936, "long": 147.32941
>   }, "Perth2": { "lat": -31.93333, "long": 115.83333 }, "Townsville": {
>   "lat": -19.25, "long": 146.8 } } } } }, { "model": "viewer.net", "pk":
>   2, "fields": { "net_name": "Abilene-tz", "data": { "graph_data": {
>   "nodes": ["Houston", "Indianapolis", "Chicago", "Los,Angeles",
>   "Denver", "New,York", "Washington,DC", "Sunnyvale", "Kansas,City",
>   "Atlanta", "Seattle"], "links": [["Houston", "Kansas,City"],
>   ["Houston", "Atlanta"], ["Houston", "Los,Angeles"], ["Indianapolis",
>   "Kansas,City"], ["Indianapolis", "Atlanta"], ["Indianapolis",
>   "Chicago"], ["Chicago", "New,York"], ["Los,Angeles", "Sunnyvale"],
>   ["Denver", "Kansas,City"], ["Denver", "Seattle"], ["Denver",
>   "Sunnyvale"], ["New,York", "Washington,DC"], ["Washington,DC",
>   "Atlanta"], ["Sunnyvale", "Seattle"]] }, "city_data": { "Houston": {
>   "lat": 29.76328, "long": -95.36327 }, "Indianapolis": { "lat":
>   39.76838,

...

> "Eastern,Province": { "lat": -13.0, "long": 32.25 },
>   "Northern,Province": { "lat": -11.0, "long": 31.0 }, "Livingstone": {
>   "lat": -17.84194, "long": 25.85425 }, "University,of,Zambia": { "lat":
>   -15.40809, "long": 28.28636 } } } } } ]

It is 54169 lines long and UTF-8 encoded. I am trying to load this fixture into a postgresql database. Is there any way to get a more helpful error message?

Comment: Have u tried using an IDE to format the json file to confirm that there is no error in it?

Comment: No, I use Vim. Good Idea. I will try that!

Comment: I used [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and found out that some of my data were bad. After fixing each instance, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help. You can just give my comment an Up Vote.